# Como extrair valores de um arquivo .txt e atribuir ou substituir o valor no codigo python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython-notebook

Boa noite.
Vou tentar ilustrar da melhor forma possível, creio que seja uma tarefa fácil, mas já pesquisei e não achei nada direto ao ponto que eu quero.

meu codigo é esse:

```
from var import *
a1 = a + b
a2 = a + c
a3 = b + c

print(a1, a2, a3)
```

o arquivo chama-se: **var.txt**
nele está assim:

```
a = 1
b = 5
c = 10
```

o erro que era esperado é o seguinte:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'var'**

- Porque creio que o python não reconhece o .txt como uma biblioteca ou arquivo externo.

Comment: Já experimentou trocar o nome do arquivo texto de `var.txt` para `var.py` .Veja se ajuda [Sistema de importação Python](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/import.html#the-path-based-finder).

Comment: já, mas depois de empacotado o app em '.exe', queria que ele lê-se o .txt. Entretanto se a solução for muito complexa vou abortar a pesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente a forma que estava tentando abrir o arquivo de texto estaria errada.

```
with open('var.txt', 'r') as open:
data = open.read().splitlines()

val = {}
for line in data:
    letra, valor = line.split('=')
    val[letra] = int(valor)
a1 = val['a'] + val['b']
a2 = val['a'] + val['c']
a3 = val['b'] + val['c']

print(a1, a2, a3)
```

O Que esta acontecendo rapidamente explicado, pois deixei recomendações de como poderia resultar este mesmo resultado seguindo a documentação do python. Com 'with open' para abrir o arquivo, a variável 'open' que vai ter como atribuição o arquivo aberto, '.read()' na linha abaixo foi usado para ler o conteúdo e o '.splitlines()' foi usado para dividir as strings em uma lista de linhas, removendo todos os caracteres de quebra de linha.

A variável 'val' vai criar um dicionário com os valores do arquivo txt.
Posteriormente o 'for' vai estar dizendo que para cada linha do arquivo, ele vai realizar uma separação dos objetos encontrados usando o 'line.split('=')'. Assim separando a letra do numero. e abaixo realizando a soma dos mesmo e por fim imprimindo os mesmos na tela.

Espero que minha resposta esteja correta, a explicação não ficou tão boa, mas é  isso ai.

Recomendações:

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html